# return types and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <iostream>
struct X
{
     X(const char *) { std::cout  << 1; }
     X(const X&) {std::cout << 2;} //copy ctor;
     X(X&& ) {std::cout << 3;} //Move ctor;
};

X f(X a)
{
    return a; //a will be moved out of f calling X's move ctor
}

X g(const char* b)
{
    X c(b); 
    return c;
}
int main()
{
   f("hello");
   g("hello");

   //prints 131 and not 1313
}
```

Output of the the program above is 131 why ? as per my understanding it should be 1313

i.e. when f returns move constructor is called on the same lines move constructor should also be called when g returns.

Comment: Look up "copy elision, particularly "return value optimization".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to ACCU 2014! :-)

In `f`, one gets implicit move of `a` because you are returning a by-value function parameter.

In `g` one gets implicit move of `c` because you are returning a local automatic-storage variable.

With only this information, then your understanding is correct:  1313.  And if a compiler output this, it would be conforming.

The extra information comes from [class.copy]/p31 which describes when "return value optimization" (RVO) is allowed.  RVO is not allowed in `f`, but is allowed in `g`.  There really is no good reason I'm aware of that RVO isn't allowed in `f`, except for the fact that no compiler I'm aware of has figured out how to implement it.  And so there has been no motivation to change the spec to allow it.

All compilers I'm aware of implement RVO for `g`, and thus the final move construction is optimized away -- even though it has side effects.  So RVO isn't a "pure optimization".  And because of this, in order to implement it, the standard has to give special permission for this (observable) "optimization."

Comment: Thanks Howard for the explanation and indeed, this question is from the pub quiz at ACCU2014 :-)  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Compilers can optimize the code and remove the call to the copy constructor for returning objects. There is even a special exception in the C++ standard to allow this because this optimization changes observable behavior of your program. Search fro RVO (return value optimization) and NRVO (named return value optimization). Some compilers, e.g. msvc, even do this when optimization are disabled.

Comment: can anyone please specify the rules governing RVO ? In this example both return values are named values!

Comment: Ask your compiler vendor about this... For msvc, there are some articles about it you can find when you google for mvcs and nvro